# How to setup and use Apache arrow from within Xcode C++ project

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode6, apache-arrow

I need to read and write some parquet.gzip files within my C++ project in Xcode. From what I understand I should use the library Arrow from Apache. However I am struggling to use it within my Xcode project.

I downloaded it with

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/arrow.git
cd arrow
brew update && brew bundle --file=cpp/Brewfile
```

navigated to the directory and

```
cd arrow/cpp
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. --preset ninja-debug-minimal
cmake --build .
```

Now I am not sure about how to use the library in my C++ XCode project.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this section of the docs that discusses this topic:

https://arrow.apache.org/docs/developers/cpp/building.html#debugging-with-xcode-on-macos